# MS Access VBA to change a field in report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have code like bellow

```
  strSQLWplacili = "Wplacili_2018"

  DoCmd.OpenReport "Wplacili_2017", acViewDesign, , , acHidden
  Set objRPT = Reports("Wplacili_2017")
  objRPT.RecordSource = strSQLWplacili

  Set objLBL = objRPT.Controls("Etykieta10")
  objLBL.Caption = "Something"

  '  Save report changes:
  DoCmd.Close acReport, "Wplacili_2018", acSaveYes
```

Now I want to change the source of one field named 'dane-skladka' from report.
the source format for this field is skladka_2017 and I want it to be skladka_2018 how can I do it by using VBA?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkGhI.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
Me("dane-składka").ControlSource = "składka_2018"
```

Comment: Yes that is it. Thank You!